# Is it possible to use Wildcards for checking with Numerical columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql

For example, Im using the below query and I get the following error correspondingly

```
SELECT MIN(amt) FROM trnsact 
WHERE amt NOT LIKE '0%';
```

Here, amt is the purchase amt and so I want to find out the cheapest purchase amount using the query above but there are a lot of rows with values like 0, 0.1 0.02 etc. I dont want all those. I want values as less as 1 maybe.
The error i get is:

Error Code - 3544 
Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 3544] [SQLState HY000] Partial string matching requires character operands.

Please help guys!!!

Comment: Why wouldn't `amt >= 1` be better?

Comment: That is correct. I dont know why I din think of that. Thank u @Uueerdo :)

Comment: And for cases where you might actually want to use wildcards (e.g. checking for the presence of a digit within the number) you could cast the number to varchar for the comparison: `CAST(amt AS VARCHAR)` or implicitly with `CONCAT(amt)`.

Comment: @hsan [`CAST(amt AS CHAR)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: @Uueerdo Oh right. mysql doesn't cast to varchar...

Comment: @hsan I make the same mistake all the time; was just fresh in my mind because someone recommended it to another question a week or so back, and the questioner couldn't get it to work for the (sort of) obvious reason.

Comment: Thanks @Uueerdo and @hsan; appreciate both of your inputs. My apologies for the delay in response but I am becoming more focused on my profession and taking my questions seriously on Stack Overflow and I appreciate both of you for having spent your time and energy to analyze and provide a solution for my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use

```
SELECT MIN(amt) FROM trnsact WHERE amt >= 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it @Sami